# hazelcast tcp client for extended service via spi

Tags: java, tcp, client, hazelcast

I've read documentation about extending hazelcast http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#extending-hazelcast as I am doing almost exactly same thing.
unfortunately the documentation just present how to connect from member app that has access to CounterService and is able to obtain proxy instance.

I try to create client that can interact with CounterService from outside of a HC cluster via TCP. Can anyone point me where I can read more about it.
are there any reasons such interaction was not described in manual?

Or is this as simple as configuring java native client somehow?
I am a bit confused, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need. You need to configure the Java Native Client. Its configuration is very well described on the HAzelcast website and is also very similar to the configuration of the Hazelcast server.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6.2/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-java-client

More or less this is what you need to configure it:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("10.90.0.1", "10.90.0.2:5702");
```

Once you obtain instance of HazelcastInstance (the client one). You can get a handler to your distributed object by using:

```
instance.getDistributedObject(CounterService.NAME, k+"counter")
```

Based on your comment I see that you have not yet defined a Proxy and an Operation for your Service. please read the following documentation carefully and post your code if you need additional help:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/spiproxy.html

Comment: Ok but how you can then use API my Counter service is exposing? (in documentation Counter has inc() method). still this is unclear to me how to connect those two pieces.

Comment: Ok you need 4 things. 1 a service - I believe you have it already. 2. You need to have a proxy that will act as a local gateway to the service. This proxy should be created from within the createDistributedObject method in your service. 3. You need to define operation extending AbstractOperation 3. You need client code, this code is above in my answer. Once you get the the Distributed object from your client with instance.getDistributedObject(CounterService.NAME, k+"counter")  you can cast it to

Comment: I am setting my test infrastructure and verify this works the way you are describing it. so there is no runtime validation if obtained proxy is the one that actually can manipulate with the remote service.

Answer (score 0):

so meanwhile I asked same question on hazelcast's group and first they will try to add missing documentation about the topic. second you need use client generator from your own interfaces.

here is a link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/QS1UovGLOhQ